# Unfortunately app has stopped issue in android app

Tags: android

i have this source code which i am trying to make it work, i took it from a tutorial online.
The issue with it is that i get an error:
"Unfortunately MainScreen has stopped" ;

Now, i looked online to find a possible solution and found that it might be in AndroidManifest.xml and i changed the name of the ap to com.example.androidhive and no chance again..

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidhive"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >


        <activity
            android:name=".MainScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- All Product Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".AllProductsActivity"
            android:label="All Products" >
        </activity>

        <!-- Add Product Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".NewProductActivity"
            android:label="Add New Product" >
        </activity>

        <!-- Edit Product Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".EditProductActivity"
            android:label="Edit Product" >
        </activity>
    </application>

    <!--  Internet Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

Thanks..

Log

```
05-06 08:29:03.940: E/AndroidRuntime(757): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-06 08:29:03.940: E/AndroidRuntime(757): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-06 08:29:03.940: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
05-06 08:29:03.940: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
05-06 08:29:03.940: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
05-06 08:29:03.940: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
05-06 08:29:03.940: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
05-06 08:29:03.940: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
05-06 08:29:03.940: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
05-06 08:29:03.940: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-06 08:29:03.940: E/AndroidRuntime(757): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-06 08:29:03.940: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:130)
05-06 08:29:03.940: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:1)
05-06 08:29:03.940: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-06 08:29:03.940: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
05-06 08:29:03.940: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  ... 4 more
```

Comment: you need to learn how to use logcat ...

Comment: We need LogCat output. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your log cat showing `NullPointerException`

```
05-06 08:29:03.940: E/AndroidRuntime(757): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

and it seems in line No :-  130 of AllProductsAct.java's asyncTask's doInBackground method. check that line there should be a variable which is not assigned yet.

```
05-06 08:29:03.940: E/AndroidRuntime(757):  at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:130)
```

post your code also.